# How do I ignore default EntityData properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-mobile-services

I am creating an `MVC mobile application service` using `Entity Framework`

I have created an `Entity Model` like so:

```
public class Regions : EntityData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I have created a `TableController` so I query by making a get request to:

```
http://localhost:3000/tables/Regions
```

This returns an error saying:

> "exceptionMessage": "Invalid column name 'Id'.\r\nInvalid column name >'Version'.\r\nInvalid column name 'CreatedAt'.\r\nInvalid column
>   name 'UpdatedAt'.",

Looking into the `EntityData` class I can see these are properties of the `EntityData` class:

```
public abstract class EntityData : ITableData
{
    protected EntityData();

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Index(IsClustered = true)]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.CreatedAt)]
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Deleted)]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.UpdatedAt)]
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Version)]
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

So the query Generated is

```
'SELECT 
     [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
     [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
     [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
     [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
     [Extent1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
     [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted]
     FROM [dbo].[Region] AS [Extent1]''
```

Which is obviously why the query fails.

Is it possible to exclude these default `EntityData` columns as they are not in my table `Regions`?

Comment: It's important to note that the fields provided by ITableData are required to support the Azure Mobile client SDKs.  Version is for supporting ETag.  UpdatedAt & Version is for supporting offline sync capabilities and Deleted is for supporting soft-delete capabilities in multi-client offline-sync scenarios.  If you remove these fields, then you cannot use the Azure Mobile client SDKs.  Setting the service to use "Dynamic Schema" will add the fields back into your database for you.

Comment: @AdrianHall Thanks for the comment. I am infact using Azure Mobile Client SDK. So its a really good thing you mentioned it. How would I go about setting the service to use `Dynamic Schema`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to hide base class attributes with key new:

```
public new DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
```

Then add attribute `[NotMapped]`:

```
[NotMapped]
public new DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
```

Finally result:

```
public class Regions : EntityData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public new DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public new DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public new byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know how you want to treat id in this case. If you need to hide the base class property add new before type.

Comment: just to clarify I would hide the base class property and mark it as `[NotMapped]` Can you do a quick example with my `Regions` class hiding a property?