# How do I add Default Entity Framework Columns to my Existing Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am creating an `MVC Azure mobile application service` using `Entity Framework`

I have created an `Entity Model` like so:

```
public class Regions : EntityData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and I have created a TableController so I query by making a get request to:

```
http://localhost:3000/tables/Regions
```

This returns an error saying:

> "exceptionMessage": "Invalid column name 'Id'.\r\nInvalid column name
>   'Version'.\r\nInvalid column name 'CreatedAt'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UpdatedAt'.",

The query generated in the output is:

```
'SELECT 
     [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
     [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
     [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
     [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
     [Extent1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
     [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted]
     FROM [dbo].[Region] AS [Extent1]''
```

So my question is How do I add these columns to my already existing database so that my `mobile app service` will work?

**PS.** This is connected to a comment on an earlier question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723280/how-do-i-ignore-default-entitydata-properties#comment57199520_34723280)

Comment: have you tried to use migrations?

Comment: @FabioLuz I'm not sure what migrations is? Do you have any links I can read up on?

Comment: Try these: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx   http://www.mortenanderson.net/code-first-migrations-for-entity-framework    http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for a new service, where you're not using an existing database, creating the tables and the their columns (not only the default Mobile Apps columns but also the columns to back the model you're defining as you change it) should be as simple as using the correct EF database initialization strategy.

You'll notice that your service template has created a database initializer for you, typically named `MobileServiceInitializer`, which may inherit from `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MobileServiceContext>`.

While developing, changing the base class used by your initializer to `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MobileServiceContext>` or `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MobileServiceContext>` (which will do exactly what the name says) will automatically change the database to match the model you have defined (which includes the default columns).

That should give you what you need while developing but as mentioned before, a more long term solution is to adopt EF migrations. You can learn more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Also, as mentioned by Adrian, your Region class is defining an Id property, which **hides** the implementation provided by EntityData and may lead to issues, so removing it is recommended.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the response. I will read the link you posted. I'm guessing `DropCreateDatabase` will delete the existing data in the database. I will research `Migrations` more to see if I can find what I need

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct. DropCreateDatabaseX will delete the data. When you're initially defining your model and locally developing the service, that shouldn't be an issue, but definitely not something that would be recommended when running against a production database (or any database you care about).

Answer (score 2):

The EntityData object contains definitions for five required fields:

```
[Id] [nvarchar](255) Default (CONVERT([nvarchar](255),newid(),(0))) NOT NULL  Primary Key,
[CreatedAt] [datetimeoffset](3) DEFAULT CONVERT([datetimeoffset](3),sysutcdatetime(),(0)) NOT NULL,
[UpdatedAt] [datetimeoffset](3)  DEFAULT CONVERT([datetimeoffset](3),sysutcdatetime(),(0)) NOT NULL,
[Version] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
[Deleted] [bit] DEFAULT 0 NULL,
```

Your id is overwriting the definition in the EntityData object.  Also, your SQL database does not have the other required fields.  I'm assuming you are not doing migrations, so the database is not being updated with the new definition.